# Multi threading functionality in an OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I am having trouble implementing multi-threading functionality for my OpenGL application. I am trying to achieve the rendering of multiple videos at the same time without delaying video frame in the application. My code is below.

```
   AppData data[4];
   std::vector<VideoRender*>videolayer;
   VideoRender* videovector = NULL;


   Sprite_Renderer  *Renderer;
```

this portion of code initializes the video render class from another file.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        videovector = new VideoRender();
        videovector->initializeAppData(&data[i]);
        videovector->openVideoFrame(&data[i], filename[i]);
        videolayer.push_back(videovector);
    }
```

to openvideo file and read video frame from video file.

```
effect->BeginRender();

//video 1
 videovector->readFrame(&data[0]);
    Renderer->DrawSprite(* ResourceManager::GetTexture("MatchSideBackGrounds"),
                         glm::vec2(0, 0), glm::vec2(this->Width, this->Height), 0.0f
    );

//video 2
 videovector->readFrame(&data[1]);
    Renderer->DrawSprite(* ResourceManager::GetTexture("MatchSideBackGrounds"),
                         glm::vec2(0, 0), glm::vec2(this->Width, this->Height), 0.0f
    );

 effect->EndRender();
```

you can see that it is sequence functionality to render video in my app which quite slow and inefficient to run play video. However, video frames quality is same as original video but render is very slow compare to original videofile. how can I implement multithreading for readFrame to render video fast and without delays of the frame?

I also tired

```
  std::thread first(&EVTVideo::paravideo, this);
first.join();

void EVTVideo::paravideo(){
    videovector->readFrame(&data[0]);
    Renderer->DrawSprite(* ResourceManager::GetTexture("MatchSideBackGrounds"),
                         glm::vec2(0, 0), glm::vec2(this->Width, this->Height), 0.0f
    );
    std::cout << "From Thread ID 1 : "<<std::this_thread::get_id() << "\n";
}
```

it didn't worked.

what are the possible ways to solve this issue or implement multi-threading functionality?

Comment: In general, if you want to use OpenGL from multiple threads, you will have to use multiple contexts. But if atm the GPU performance is the bottleneck, I highly doubt that you would get a better performance with multithreading since the GPU is still a single resource and can't do more work if used from multiple CPU threads. If the CPU is the problem now, then you should reformulate your question to reflect that and show the relevant parts that use the CPU too much.

Comment: Your question is way too broad to really give you a meaningful answer. But that aside, Multithreading and OpenGL doesn't really work very well. If you want to call OpenGL functions from multiple threads, each thread would need to have it's own context and you need to share data between them. That comes with a huge overhead + increase in complexity and therefore is not really worth the effort most of the time. The majority of applications using OpenGL leave all api calls to just one thread dedicated to it. I recommend you to just not go down that rabbit hole.

Comment: @Eric it's kind of disappointing that  **Multithreading and OpenGL doesn't really work very well.**  how can I render multiple videos at the same time? it difficult but not impossible to do that.

Comment: @Eric what if dynamic programing or caching algorthim to slove this issue?

Answer (score -1):

> CUDA is a parallel computing platform and application programming
>   interface model created by Nvidia. It allows software developers and
>   software engineers to use a CUDA-enabled graphics processing unit for
>   general purpose processing – an approach termed GPGPU.

it is the answer to render to multiple objects parallel in OpenGL. 
https://github.com/przemyslawzaworski/CPP-Programming/blob/master/CUDA/tetrahedron.cu